# Aimed so squarely

Tags: idioms

> History professors assign books with formulaic arguments that
>   transform history into an abstract debate that would have been
>   unfathomable to those who lived in the past. **Aimed so squarely at
>   the head,** such books cannot stimulate students who yearn to connect
>   to history emotionally as well as intellectually.

What does **Aimed so squarely** means? I think it means "Too focused on head(which is knowledge and facts, not emotion)" Am I understanding it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly a metaphor.

"Squarely" can mean "at right angles", and if you are aiming (a gun, a bow etc) at a target, you want to be square to the target. If you are aiming squarely, you are aiming from in front of your target.

The "head" represents the intellectual, thinking, objective part of a person's personality, in contrast to the heart, which is emotional, feelings, subjective part.

History books which are "aimed so squarely at the head" is a metaphor. The content is directly targeted at the intellectual, not the emotional part of the reader's personality.

Comment: I have two interpretations for the last sentence. 1. Too focused on knowledge, such books cannot satisfy those students who seek for both emotional and intellectual connections. 2. Too focused on knowledge, such books cannot satisfy two group of students: students who seek for emotional connection and students who seek for intellectual connection. Which one is correct?